# Mysql query select where before join

Tags: mysql, inner-join

My two tables look like this

websites table

```
| id | website | etc. |
```

websites_statistics table

```
| id | website_id | etc. |
```

I want to join statistics table with a results from website table. the first record is getting by the website name, after I need to use that id to take the website_statistics. Something like this.

```
SELECT * FROM websites WHERE websites.website = 'google.com'
INNER JOIN websites_statistics ON website.id = websites_statistics.website_id
LIMIT 0,1
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to get one record from *each* website, or just the first record you come across with a statistic?

Comment: Your query looks basically correct, just put the WHERE clause *after* the INNER JOIN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM websites 
INNER JOIN websites_statistics ON website.id =  websites_statistics.website_id
WHERE websites.website = 'google.com'    
LIMIT 0,1
```